# my netlogo code doesnt seem to have any problems, but my agents dont appear

Tags: netlogo, agent

I am just learning to use netlogo, and I was trying to code a simple model to have different agents [breeds] perform different tasks. The agents that appear on the interface/universe are selected with a chooser...

This is what I wrote in my code:

---

```
breed [escarabajos escarabajo]; type of beetles that survive in forests
breed [beetles beetle]; type of beetles that survive in agricultural areas 

;For each breed there are three sub-types of beetles, depending on how far they can move (vagility) this is also selected with a chooser. 

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; SETUP ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to setup

  ca

  setup-patches

  set-default-shape turtles "bug"

  ask turtles [create-bichos]

  reset-ticks 
  
end

to setup-patches

  ask n-of 100 patches [ set pcolor green ]

  ask n-of 500 patches [set pcolor yellow]

end

to create-bichos

  if breed = "escarabajo" [

    ask patches with [ pcolor = green ] [

      let k forest-carrying-capacity ; what I want is to create the maximum amount of beetles ;possible per patch, and this maximum is determined with a carrying capacity value, which is set ;with a slider.... 

      sprout-escarabajos k [set color 116 set size 6]
      ]
  ]
  
   if breed = "beetle" [

    ask patches with [ pcolor = yellow ] [

        let k agricultural-carrying-capacity

        sprout-beetles k [set color 76 set size 6] 
      ]
  ]

end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; GO ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


to go

  if ticks = 72 [stop]

  ask turtles [rt random 360

    move
  ]
  

end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; PROCEDURES ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to move

  if vagility = "High"

  [ask turtles [

    move-to one-of patches in-radius 2 

  ]
  ]
  
  if vagility = "medium"

  [ask turtles [

   move-to one-of neighbors

  ]
 ]
  
  if vagility = "low"

  [ask turtles [

   move-to one-of neighbors4

  ]
]

end
```

---

Like I said, the code doesnt seem to have any problem, but when i hit the setup button, only the different colored patches appear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the line `ask turtles [create-bichos]`. This has three problems. (1) You don't have any turtles yet, so there are no turtles to ask, so the create-bichos procedure is not called. (2) If you did have some turtles already, then EACH of those turtles would call the procedure, so they would be asking the patches to do things multiple times. (3) `breed` is an attibute of turtles, you can't use it as the name of the chooser.

As a learner, you need to write smaller bits of code and make sure each one works before moving on. So let's imagine that you start by creating the turtles (since that's your question) and your chooser is called 'breed-select'. The solution is to simply remove the `ask turtles`, but as a first pass you should simply create a fixed number of turtles before introducing more code.

```
breed [escarabajos escarabajo]; type of beetles that survive in forests
breed [beetles beetle]; type of beetles that survive in agricultural areas 

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  set-default-shape turtles "bug"
  create-bichos
  reset-ticks 
end

to setup-patches
  ask n-of 100 patches [ set pcolor green ]
  ask n-of 500 patches [set pcolor yellow]
end

to create-bichos
  if breed-selector = "escarabajo"
  [ ask patches with [ pcolor = green ]
    [ sprout-escarabajos 5 [set color 116 set size 6]
    ]
  ]
  if breed-selector = "beetle"
  [ ask patches with [ pcolor = yellow ]
    [ sprout-beetles 5 
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is so useful :D

Answer (score 0):

Use the [create agent command](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/create-turtles.html) `create-escarabajos <number>` or `create-beetles <number>` to create new agents of your custom breeds

Comment: That command is included in the code already. The problem is that the command is within a part of the code that is not called.